# localhost still work after remove it from hosts file

Tags: windows, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, localhost

I use WSL(ubuntu 22.0.4) and connecting WSL using VS Code for development.

I created a web server like this:

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('state', 'ok', { httpOnly: true });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

I removed the `127.0.0.1 localhost` record from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in Windows OS

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1       localhost
```

I also removed this record from `/etc/hosts` in WSL

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
#127.0.0.1      localhost
# 127.0.1.1     LAPTOP-C8AFGSGK.        LAPTOP-C8AFGSGK
# 127.0.0.1     localhost
# 127.0.0.1       api.example.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

As you can see, I removed all records from the hosts file not only in Windows OS but also in the WSL.

But when I access `http://localhost:3000` in the browser, it still can access the web server and get the response.

[image]

I use the DNS lookup provided by `edge://net-internals/#dns`, enter the `localhost` domain, got

```
Resolved IP addresses of "localhost": ["::1","127.0.0.1"].
No data on which protocols are supported.
```

It seems the `localhost` domain still points to `127.0.0.1`.

I expect the `http://localhost:3000` should not access the web server, only the `http://127.0.0.1:3000` can access the web server. What am I missing?

Comment: The *hosts* file comment already explains this. Which further information do you seek?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/4689

Comment: The use of `#` characters at the start of lines indicates a comment, eg they're not configuration settings that you can set/change, simply comments to provide information. The reason being that you can't change/remove localhost, it always exists, it isn't controlled via hosts, and it's always at those addresses.

Comment: 127.0.90.1 is the loopback IP address, and is actually built into the OS and network card. See https://www.howtogeek.com/789017/what-is-the-127.0.0.1-ip-address-and-how-do-you-use-it/ and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/127-0-0-1-localhost . BTW, I needed to set up two servers on a PC, and used 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.3 -- distinct IP addresses, but allowing the PC to talk to itself.

Comment: I don't know why people vote to close this for reasons like clarity or not being on topic. The question is very clear. It could very likely be a duplicate, but closing this for lack of clarity is pure nonsense.